# Gmail API sends multiple mails during bulk sending

Tags: python, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I am looking to send bulk emails using the Gmail API. I have an implementation using a for loop, which changes the receiver's email in every iteration, and creates a new message, and executes the service.

The problem is I observe multiple emails going to the same mail id. Since I am new to using Gmail API, I'm unaware of the root cause for this issue.

**Code:**

```
# receiver_path contains file with emails separated by comma
f = open(receiver_path, "r")
receivers = (f.read()).split(',')

message = MIMEText(body_txt)
message['from'] = senders_email
message['subject'] = subject

while i < (len(receivers)):
    a = min(45, len(receivers)-i)
    for j in range(a):
        message['to'] = str(receivers[i + j])

        raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
        raw = raw.decode()
        final_message = {'raw': raw}

        try:
            message_temp = (service.users().messages().send(userId=senders_email, body=final_message)
                            .execute())
        except BaseException as e:
            print('Could not send mail: ', e)
            print('Mail id #' + str(i + j + 1))

    sleep(1.5)

    print('Mail delivered to set ' + str(int(i / 45) + 1))
    i += 45
```

**What I have tried?:**

1. Sleep after execution of every mail instead of every batch.
2. Debugged the code, the logic of loops is working as expected.

Comment: Where is `receivers` populated from? In what order are the messages being sent?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo my bad, previous receiver_txt was supposed to be receivers. The order in which they are initiated is same as the order of how they are in the list, but the order of when they are sent, I'm not able to find out since they reach at the same time

Comment: Implement a sleep between sends and check out the received times, it may give an indication as to where the duplication is coming from

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Yeah, I tried that, in that case, the order is the same as the order in which I set the list. However, I observed that when I don't sleep between every mail, the to list is appending new receiver's mail id instead of setting, so first receiver gets many mail (= length of receivers' list). Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you provide a dummy data set so I can test it locally?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo yeah consider taking:

`receivers = [ 'emai1', 'email2', 'email3' ]`
`message = MIMEText('Body')`
`message['from'] = 'your_email_as_in_token'`
`message['subject'] = 'subject'`